# AutoLayout debugger shows (null) ((null), (null)) for constraints with no useful information

Tags: xcode, autolayout, flkautolayout

I am working with AutoLayout and am using a library called ***FLKAutoLayout***. When I have a conflict the autolayout debug messages that I am used to do not always show useful information about the constraints in conflict.

Has anyone seen this before and know how to resolve these messages?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From taking a look at `FLKAutoLayout` it looks like your problem is with this line in [NSLayoutConstraint+FLKAutoLayoutDebug.m](https://github.com/floriankugler/FLKAutoLayout/blob/8cb911654b3538c0ce514701db041d32964ea17c/FLKAutoLayout/Private/NSLayoutConstraint%2BFLKAutoLayoutDebug.m) :

```
`return [description stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@ (%@, %@)", asciiArtDescription, [self.firstItem flk_nameTag], [self.secondItem flk_nameTag]];`
```

`asciiArtDescription` is a private method on NSLayoutConstraint, while `flk_nameTag` is an property added as an "associated object".

Are you working in Swift? It could be something interfering with the program's ability to do those two things, even though it's in objective-C code. You could try creating a test project in Objective C that recreates the warnings to see if they appear.